# Azure App Configuration - sentinel key not working?

Tags: azure-app-configuration

Using [this documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-aspnet-core), I set up a sentinel key to reduce the number of times my app checks for changes, but it's not working as expected so maybe I'm misunderstanding how this works?

My understanding of how it should work:

> By default (without refresh configured in anyway), my app will check
> for changes on all my imported keys every 30 seconds.
>
> By configuring a refresh with a sentinel, my app will check only the
> sentinel key for changes every 30 seconds (if cache expiration is not
> changed). Only when the sentinel key value changes will the values for
> other imported keys be checked.

What I'm seeing:

> Every time I change ANY key, my app immediately pulls down the change. Even if I don't configure the refresh, changes to my sentinel are pulled into the app (my sentinel key is not configured to be pulled into my app). In fact, keys with prefixes that are not imported into my app trigger update calls from my app. Any time any key is updated regardless of inclusion in my `Select` they are called for and updated.

How I'm seeing updates being called for:

> I am using Fiddler to monitor my network traffic.

My configuration:

```
builder
    .ConfigurationBuilder
    .AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
    {
        options.Connect(new Uri(azConnStr), new DefaultAzureCredential())
            .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
            {
                kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
            });

        if (configurationKeyPrefixes != null
            && configurationKeyPrefixes.Any()) 
        { 
            foreach (var prefix in configurationKeyPrefixes)
            {
                options
                    .TrimKeyPrefix($"{prefix}/")
                    .Select($"{prefix}/*", LabelFilter.Null);
            }
        }

        options.ConfigureRefresh(refreshOpts =>
        {
            refreshOpts.Register("refreshSentinel", LabelFilter.Null, true);
        });
    });
```

Repo
https://github.com/mmulhearn/azure-app-config-repo/tree/main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm using Azure Function apps and you have to setup DI and a handler as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-azure-functions-csharp). Once I did the proper DI and invoked `TryRefreshAsync()` everything started to work as expected and it *clicked* for me. Hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

Clarify some expectations:

If `ConfigureRefresh` is not called, no keys will be monitored, and there will be no configuration refresh.

If `ConfigureRefresh` is called and you register at least one key to monitor, your app will check for changes every 30s (the default) supposing your app is active. If a change is detected, your app will either reload all key-values you selected (`refreshAll` is true) or just the key you monitor (`refreshAll` is false).

The key you monitor (e.g. the "sentinel" key) is always pulled into your app regardless of if it's part of the `Select`.

Comment: My understanding is that the sentinel key is used so it doesn't monitor all keys, just the sentinel key. However, I'm not seeing that. I can update any key and it'll immediately pull it in despite a sentinel key being specified. From what you said and the documentation, that doesn't seem like correct behavior.

Comment: I'm still seeing that if I Register ANY value, every single key (regardless of Select inclusion) update is pulled by the application.

Comment: Which version of the `Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore` package are you using? Can you please update it to 6.0.1, if not yet? I don't expect your application picks up any configuration changes unless you update the sentinel key (or your application restarts). Can you please share a simplified repro?

Comment: I'll try to create a repo, however, `Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore` is not used in my project. I can't find it as a dependency of a dependency, either.

Comment: Repo URL added to OP